# Cannot get context to launch intent

Tags: android, android-intent, null, android-context

I've made a separate class to launch and intent as the class I would like to launch the intent from is a thread and does not inherit from activity and would not launch startActivity. Every time I launch the app I get a null pointer exception for the context.

```
public class ToLaunch extends Activity {
    public void launchScoreloop() {
        con.getApplicationContext();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LeaderboardsScreenActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't get you at all and this is a wrong way to launch a new intent....please refere some simple android examples..

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

You Are writing an Activity , and you didn't override the method `onCreate()`.

```
public class ToLaunch extends Activity {
    @override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
     //Call your method here after a  button click cor example or something else
    }

    public void launchScoreloop() {
        con.getApplicationContext();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LeaderboardsScreenActivity.class));
    }
}
```

refer this two tutorials about using intents to start another Activity : 
 [tuto 1](http://mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/how-start-another-activity)
 [tuto 2](http://www.droidnova.com/use-intents-to-start-other-activities,76.html)

And if you want to launch the Activity from another Class , you should pass the context to the second Class like this :

```
SecondClass instance = new SecondClass(this);
```

and  the contructor of your SecondClass will be something like this :

```
public void SecondClass(Context _context){
   this.context = _context;
}
```

and then you can start the Avtivity by using the context that you passed to your SecondClass like this :

```
this.context.startActivity(....);
```

Comment: I probably shouldnt have extended Activity this was only so I could use startActivity(). What I was looking for was an easy was to start an intent from within a thread that has no context passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

If thread is a inner class inside your activity you can use

```
    startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this, LeaderboardsScreenActivity.class));

    If it is a separate class you can make a constructor that take context has constructor as argument and you can pass your activity context into that constructor


    Context con;
    public YourThread(Context context){
     con = context;
    }
```

and from inside your activity, while making thread object

```
    YourThread thread = new YourThread(this);
```

Comment: It is not a generally good idea to pass Context to other threads to avoid making your Activity long lived and leaking memory. That being said you would better off using WeakReference<> for keeping Context.

Comment: Thanx for info. But what if we make context as a weak reference and it gets garbage collected before thread has used it. It will crash the app as context is null

Comment: it is better to use AsynTask to run the treatment that will modify the UI :)

Comment: @anujprashar You can check if WeakReference<> still holds a valid reference to a Context (.get() returns null) and avoid doing any action on it. +Houcine suggestion is worth investing too.